# Manage Autolayout on iOS 6 and iOS 7 for the UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, autolayout

I'm working on an iPad app for iOS 6 and iOS 7. I've activated AutoLayout and I'm having some trubles around the `UINavigationBar`.

For exemple, I have a page with my `UINavigationBar`, then a `UILabel`, and then a `UICollectionView`.

- on iOS 6 the `UILabel` appears at the right place (under the `UINavigationBar`), but the bottom of my `UICollectionView` is hidden.
- on iOS 7, it's the opposite : the `UILabel` is hidden under the `UINavigationBar`, but the bottom of the `UICollectionView` is fine.

How should I manage such a situation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Comment: Thanks ! That resolves problem #2. Now on both iOS 6 and 7 the UILabel appears at the right place (under the UINavigationBar), but the bottom of my UICollectionView is hidden. Should I change the height of my UIView in the .xib ? Or is there a property to set ?

Comment: my answer resolve the issue accept my answer and give a reputation.

Comment: There is no code to post. In my xib I have a View, landscape mode, sized 1024x768. I have no fake UINavigationBar. My UILabel's origin is (0,0). My UICollectionView is going up to the bottom of the view. Should I manually change the height of the general UIView ?

Comment: I will accept your answer when my whole problem will be solved, not just a part of it. Don't worry.

Comment: No, use constraints to adjust the widgets

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7 you should consider the `UINavigationBar` as not part of the screen, it is visible but it is not considered when drawing views. You may solve the problem working on the `xib` files with the "iOS 6/7 Deltas", adding a `deltaY` of +20 and a `deltaHeight` of -20 in iOS 7 (first of all ensure that in the File Inspector panel you have set "View as iOS 6.1 and Earlier")